# How to store image in hive?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-hive

Can anyone tell me how to store and retrieve images from the Hive database in Flutter?

I want to upload and then show that images in other page using hive, I tried but I'm not able to do that.

Comment: you can encode images that uploaded your app and save it to the DB using base64 but you have to decode it when you call back them.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by turning it to blob and save it but **Don't**, this will just make in a unnecessary mess of work

Instead you can save the file in the disk of the device then store it's path with Hive and use it

Answer (score 0):

hope you are fine,

//most simple solution

> If image's url is a simple string, then all you need is to take image's path or
> url and save it
> to hive then retrieve it again when needed.

//more complicated solution

> If url is not string or any primitive data type, then you will need to
> convert it to a `hive object` and use it normally.

- as they mentioned at official `hive docs`, "Store Objects" section:

  ```
  @HiveType(typeId: 0)
  class Person extends HiveObject {
   @HiveField(0)
   String name;
   @HiveField(1)
   int age;
  }
  ```
- then use it as normal

  ```
  var box = await Hive.openBox('myBox');
  var person = Person()
  ..name = 'Dave'
  ..age = 22;
  box.add(person);
  print(box.getAt(0)); // Dave - 22
  person.age = 30;
  person.save();
  print(box.getAt(0)) // Dave - 30
  ```
- refer to official docs for more info: [flutter hive official docs](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)
- hope I could help, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

For saving imagePath using Hive:

```
  Future<void> selectPhoto({
    ImageSource source = ImageSource.gallery,
  }) async {
    try {
      List<XFile> pickedFileList;
      if (singleImagePick || source == ImageSource.camera) {
        final XFile? photo = await _picker.pickImage(
          source: source,
          imageQuality: imageQuality,
        );
        pickedFileList = photo != null ? [photo] : [];
      } else {
        pickedFileList = await _picker.pickMultiImage(
          imageQuality: imageQuality,
        );
      }

      for (final element in images) {
        content.add(element.path);
      }
    }
  }
  

  
  @HiveField(0)
  late final List<String> content;
```